# How to change language of the django form

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a basic django form template and it's in english. I would like to change the whole form to finnish. How do i do that?

forms,py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class rekkausform(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

register.html

```html
{%extends "blogi/base.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{%block content%}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {%csrf_token%}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Liity</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Rekkkaa</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <a class="text-muted">Joko sinulla on tili? <a href="#">Kirjaudu tästä</a> </small>
        </div>
    </div>

{%endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a register form
It's possible to use [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/)

- Install django-registration and add it to INSTALLED_APPS setting.
- Setting up the URLs.
- Create the templates.
- and in registration_form.html add your code, like what you have done in your register.html
- Then in settings.py change LANGUAGE_CODE to the proper language

All the form, its labels, errors and helpers will translate to chosen language.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change the labels you need . for example you need to change the label of the username:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):


email = forms.EmailField()
username = forms.CharField(
    label = 'نام کاربری', #username in persion
    required = True,
)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```